# Advanced Custom Fields show store locations under correct state div

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields to add a listing of store locations according to state.  I want each store that belongs to it's state to populate under that state's div.  I am also using ACF for a user to add in a new state div.  I can't seem to get the code to pull in the store locations.  Can anyone help with this?

```

````
  <?php
  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'state',
      'meta_key'  => 'state_name',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value',
      'order'   => 'ASC'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  ?>

  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

  <div class="state-name-header">
    <h2 id="<?php the_field( 'state_name' ); ?>"><?php the_field( 'state_name' ); ?></h2>

        <?php
        $state = get_field('state_name');
        $state_array = $state[0];
        $state_ID = $state_array->ID;

        $stores = get_posts(array(
          'post_type' => 'stores',
          'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
              'key' => 'state_name',
              'value' => '"' . $state_ID . '"',
              'compare' => 'LIKE'
              )
            )
          ));
          ?>

          <?php if ( $stores ): ?>

            <div class="locations-container">

              <?php foreach( $stores as $store ): ?>
                <?php

                    $store_name = get_field( 'store_name' , $store->ID );
                    $store_address = get_field( 'street_address' , $store->ID );
                    $store_city = get_field( 'city' , $store->ID );
                    $store_state_abbr = get_field( 'state_abbreviation'  , $store->ID);
                    $store_zip = get_field( 'zip_code'  , $store->ID);
                    $store_phone = get_field( 'phone' , $store->ID );
                    $store_url = get_field( 'website' , $store->ID );
                ?>

                  <div class="store-location">
                    <h4 class="location-name"><?php echo $store_name; ?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $store_address ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $store_city ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $store_state_abbr ?>, <?php echo $store_zip ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $store_phone ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $store_url ?>">website</a>
                  </div>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div><!-- end locations-conatiner-->
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- end state-name-header -->
       <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
      </div><!-- end state-listings-container -->```
````

Comment: I'm confused as to your issue. You don't have any results from your query? Or none of the data is displaying properly?

Comment: I don't have any results showing at all.

Comment: What is the value if you `var_dump($stores);` ?

Comment: That's why it's not looping through anything. Your `get_posts` query isn't returning any results.

Comment: Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: Make sure to check the values of `$state`, `$state_array` and `$state_ID` that they are what you expect them to be for your query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123289/discussion-between-jenny-crawshaw-and-blake).

Comment: One minor thing that's probably not related to your issue, but may cause problems later.. The first have_posts() call in your code should be $the_query->have_posts()

Answer (score 1):

I restructured the Advanced Custom Fields to use a repeater, instead of having separate entries for the states and locations.  This worked perfectly.  Here is my adjusted query for the working code.

```

````
          <?php
          $args = array(
              'post_type' => 'location',
              'meta_key'  => 'state_name',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value',
              'order'   => 'ASC'
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

          ?>

          <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

          <div class="state-name-header">
            <h2 id="<?php the_field( 'state_name' ); ?>"><?php the_field( 'state_name' ); ?></h2>

            <div class="locations-container">

              <?php if(get_field('new_store')): ?>
                  <?php while(has_sub_field('new_store')): ?>

                    <div class="store-location">

                      <h4 class="location-name"><?php the_sub_field('store_name'); ?></h4>
                      <p><?php the_sub_field('street_address'); ?></p>
                      <p><?php the_sub_field('city'); ?></p>
                      <p><?php the_field('state_abbreviation'); ?>, <?php the_sub_field('zip_code'); ?></p>
                      <p><?php the_sub_field('phone'); ?></p>
                      <a href="<?php the_sub_field('website'); ?>">Website</a>

                    </div><!-- end store-location -->

                  <?php endwhile; ?>
              <?php endif; ?>

            </div><!-- end locations-container -->

          </div><!-- end state-name-header -->
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
      </div><!-- end state-listings-container -->```
````